# MySQL get table name as part of resultset

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables with identical structure which are used to store text phrases. For-instance:

table_1

```
id | text
1. | Hello
```

table_2.

```
id | text
1. | Goodbye
```

table_3.

```
id | text
1. | Hello
```

I want to see all of the tables that contain the text 'Hello' so my query is simply:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1, table_2, table_3 WHERE text ='Hello'
```

That tells me whether 'Hello' exists but not where it exists. The results are:

```
id | text
1. | Hello
1. | Hello
```

Is there a way to put the table name into the resultset so the resultset would look like this?

```
id | text  | table_name
1. | Hello | table_1
1. | Hello | table_3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, 'table_1' as tablename FROM table_1 WHERE text ='Hello'
union all
SELECT *, 'table_2' as tablename FROM table_2 WHERE text ='Hello'
union all
SELECT *, 'table_3' as tablename FROM table_3 WHERE text ='Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id, text, 'table_1' as tablename FROM table_1 WHERE text ='Hello'
union all
SELECT id, text, 'table_2' as tablename FROM table_2 WHERE text ='Hello'
union all
SELECT id, text, 'table_3' as tablename FROM table_3 WHERE text ='Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

The query that you want is a `union all`, not a `cross join` (what you get with a comma in the `from` clause):

```
(select 'table_1' as which, t1.* from table_1 t1 where text ='Hello')
union all
(select 'table_2' as which, t2.* from table_2 t2 where text ='Hello')
union all
(select 'table_3' as which, t3.* from table_3 t3 where text ='Hello')
```